# Is there a better pythonic way to write this code?

Tags: python

I am trying to read first and third columns from a text file and add them together.

Following code works perfectly and gives me the result I need but trying to find out if there is a better more pythonic way to write this?

```
with open('random.txt', 'r') as fn:
    next(fn)
    numbers = fn.readlines()
    first_col = [int(x.split(',')[0]) for x in numbers]
    third_col = [int(y.split(',')[2]) for y in numbers]

    result = [v + z for v, z in zip(first_col, third_col)]

    print(result)
```

The random file is literally a random file.

```
col1,col2,col3
44,65,78
55,87,98
12,32,62
```

Result:

```
[122, 153, 74]
```

Comment: you may want to look at `pandas`. It's overkill for this toy sample, but works very well with comma separated value (csv) files.

Comment: There's probably a way to avoid iterating over `numbers` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the easiest way is to just sticking to the basics, there is no correct `pythonic` way! You can make your code as easy and as complex you want.

```
import csv

res = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    #Open csv file
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    next(reader)
    #Iterate through rows and append the sum of first and third rows to a list
    for row in reader:
        res.append(int(row[0]) + int(row[2]))

print(res)
#[122, 153, 74]
```

Comment: Can't agree more. "Readability counts." and "Simple is better than complex."

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the accept :) I guess the simpler is better!

Comment: This is essentially @Unni answer except you converted his list comprehension to a full `for` loop. How can this be simpler? Or clearer?

Comment: I did not see his answer until you pointed it out now! So my statements about simpler or clearer are unrelated to his answer!

Comment: Just to make it clear, I was commenting on his statement about keeping things simple.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use `numpy` then my suggestion is to use [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html?highlight=load) function:

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('random.txt', dtype=int, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 2)).sum(axis=1).tolist()
```

Comment: @gt6989b Seems readable... cast to ints, skip the first row, split on commas, use first and third column, and sum.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip`:

```
with open('random.txt', 'r') as fn:
    next(fn)
    first_col, _, third_col  = [
        *zip(*(int(x) for x in map(lambda x: x.split(','), fn))
    ]
    ...
    results = [x+y for x, y in zip(first_col, second_col)]
```

Or if you do not need to hold the cols:

```
results = [
    x+y for x, _, y in zip(*(int(x) for x in map(lambda x: x.split(','), fn))
]
```

Comment: This is the most elegant approach in pure Python and this answer should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers provided here, you can use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package to process the file.

```
import csv
with open('random.txt', 'r') as fn:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fn)
    next(csv_reader, None)  # skip the headers
    result = [int(f)+int(t) for f,_, t in csv_reader] 
    print result
```

The easiest solution will be to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) if you are comfortable with it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('random.txt')
print df.col1 + df.col2
```

If you want the result as a `list`,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('random.txt')
res =  df.col1 + df.col2
print res.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    rows = [list(map(int, row)) for row in reader]
    sums = [v + z for v, _, z in rows]
    print(sums)  # [122, 153, 74]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is "pythonic" enough, but you're doing more work and using more space than you need to.

```
with open('random.txt', 'r') as fn:
    next(fn) # skip the first row
    total = 0
    for row in fn:
        first_col, _, third_col = row.split(',')
        total += int(first_col) + int(third_col)

print(result)
```

You could tidy this up with a function perhaps

```
def sum_row(row):
    first_col, _, third_col = row.split(',')
    return int(first_col) + int(third_col)

with open('random.txt', 'r') as fn:
    next(fn) # skip the first row
    result = sum(sum_row(row) for row in fn)

print result
```

If you need an industrial strength solution, i.e., other people are using this too and you might need to maintain it in the future, use csv.

```
import csv

def sum_row(row):
    return int(row[0]) + int(row[2])

with open('random.txt', 'r') as fn:
    reader = csv.reader(fn)
    result = sum(sum_row(row) for row in fn)
```

Comment: Excellent! What does '_' do in first_col, _, third_col?

Comment: it's a variable name that's usually used to indicate you're ignoring the value. You could replace it with `first_col, second_col, third_col = row.split(',')`, but when someone goes to read your code or you use a linter, they'll ask why you didn't use second_col. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python

Answer (score 2):

There is another option with one-liner list comprehension, but we must use the `methodcaller` higher order function, to split each line from the file.

The list comprehension gets lines from the file and then the `map` function executes a `split(",")` method on each one to transform it to a list of columns.

```
from operator import methodcaller
with open('random.txt','r') as f:
    next(f)
    sum = [ int(c1)+int(c3) for c1,_,c3 in map(methodcaller("split", ","),f)]
sum
```

The additional advantage is that we can convert it into a generator without wasting any memory.

```
from operator import methodcaller
with open('data','r') as f:
    next(f)
    v = ( int(c1)+int(c3) for c1,_,c3 in map(methodcaller("split", ","),f))
    print(list(v)) # just to print the result
```